# Linear Integer Programing: fill the package with products $A, B, C, D$

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, packing-problem

A linear integer programming problem ask to consider the next restriction: we want to fill as much as possible a package that has a capacity of $1m^3$ and we have to choose between a variety of products $A, B, C, D$ with the following dimensions:

| Product | Dimensions (cm) |
| --- | --- |
| A | $8\times 2.5 \times 0.5$ |
| B | $7\times 2 \times 0.5$ |
| C | $3\times 2 \times 0.5$ |
| D | $3\times 3 \times 0.5$ |

My try:
$$8x_1+7x_2+3x_3+3x_4\leq100$$
$$2.5x_1+2x_2+2x_3+3x_4\leq100$$
$$0.5(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)\leq100$$
With $x_1,...,x_4\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.

But I think I'm not considering combinations between different dimensions. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Is the objective to find a way to _completely_ fill the $1m^3$ package?

Comment: Is not necessary. I made the edits needed. Thanks!

Comment: So the objective is to minimize the volume of the empty space. Are you required to have at least one of each type $A,B,C,D$?

Comment: This is just a restriction from a problem that asks me to maximize the quantity of sugar of these products. There is no reestricción that requires to have at least one of each.

Comment: You can’t solve this without knowing the dimensions of the package. And please check your equations. 8 x 2.5 = 20 for example. Try manually for a package of 100x100x100 and one of 125x80x100 cm.

Comment: The dimension of the package is $1m^3$ as I wrote on the problem.

Comment: That’s the total volume. What if your package is 2.45 x 0.95 x 429,645 cm in size? You won’t be able to fill more than 43% of the package.

Comment: I can’t see any sugar in your question. What about fixing it for people who are not mind readers?

Comment: Does the term "package" mean "box"?

Comment: @SofíaContreras Usually you solve such problems with a heuristic procedure. If you are interested in it give a reply.

Answer (score 1):

The idea you are attempting is correct for one dimension but not for three dimensions.  I suggest considering a much smaller problem in two dimensions to gain some insight: two products $A$ (dimensions $2 \times 1$) and $B$ (dimensions $1 \times 1$) in a $2 \times 2$ package.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume "package" means "box", so the alignment matters.

Using only boxes of type $B$ and $C$, there's an obvious way to completely fill the $1m^3$ box.

The idea is to adjoin one box of type $B$ and one box of type $C$ to effectively create a box of type, say $E$, with dimensions (in cm)
$$\textbf{l}{\,\times\,}\textbf{w}{\,\times\,}\textbf{h}=10{\,\times\,}2{\,\times\,}0.5$$
Then the bottom level (height $0.5$cm) of the $1m^3$ box can be completely filled with $500$ boxes of type $E$, arranged $10$ lengthwise and $50$ widthwise.

Then replicating the bottom level $200$ times completely fills the $1m^3$ box.